# Wrap Text in TouchableOpacity nested in Text

Tags: react-native

Including `onPress` inside a `Text` component will cause an ugly gray highlight to appear (for a split second) on the text when pressed.

Rather than having the gray highlight, I want the text to become slightly transparent while being pressed. This can easily be accomplished by wrapping the `Text` component in a `TouchableOpacity`. However, including this within another `Text` component is a different story. According to [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html#nested-views-ios-only) and the fact that `TouchableOpacity` returns a [`View`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/Touchable/TouchableOpacity.js#L176-L197) component, I have to specify a width and a height in order to accomplish this... and it's only possible on iOS.

How can I include a "pressable" `Text` component--that undergoes an opacity change when pressed--within another `Text` component?

```html
<Text/>
   Click <TouchableOpacity onPress={...}><Text>Here</Text></TouchableOpacity>
<Text/>
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to nest non-text components into `Text` on Android. Why don't you do `<Text>Click</Text><TouchableOpacity …><Text>Here</Text></TouchableOpacity>`?

Comment: That would result in "Click" and "Here" appearing on different lines.

Comment: not if you style it properly. Look at `flexbox`.

Comment: so you are telling, to accomplish this I would have to wrap my components in `<View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>` and if I wanted to right-align them, I would have to wrap that in yet another `View` component with `alignItems: "flex-end"` or is there a shorter way?

Comment: have you tried usign activeOpacity property of TouchableOpacity? or Using TouchableHighlight and using underlayColor prop for custom color ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <Text>Click</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={...}><Text>Here</Text></TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43561819/wrap-text-in-touchableopacity-nested-in-text/64474491#comment74178259_43561819

Comment: oh yes, great, sorry, I didn't see

Comment: There is one downside. If you want the whole text to be selectable it doesn't work anymore...